# Predicting future values with Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am working on a project where I take the last 50 days of data and sum the mutations of each day. This data is split into 40 as train data and then 10 as validation data. This is then used to train the model. I validated the model and it is quite accurate as you can see in the picture below:

[image: Trained model predictions]

Blue is actual data and the orange is the predicted data. Now I want to be able to predict data in the future that is still unknown and can not be validated, I do not yet know how.

Here is the code I have as of now:

1. Data splitting

```py
series = np.array(count)
time = np.array(timesteps)

split_time = 40
time_train = time[:split_time]
x_train = series[:split_time]
time_valid = time[split_time:]
x_valid = series[split_time:]
```

2. Creating function for a windowed dataset:

```py
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
  series = tf.expand_dims(series, axis=-1)
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  ds = ds.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_size + 1))
  ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
  ds = ds.map(lambda w: (w[:-1], w[1:]))
  return ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

3. Create the actual dataset:

```py
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.random.set_seed(51)
np.random.seed(51)
shuffle_buffer_size = 1000
window_size = 39
batch_size = 32
train_set = windowed_dataset(x_train, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size)
print(train_set)
print(x_train.shape)
```

4. Compile and train the model:

```py
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=60, kernel_size=5,
    strides=1, padding="causal",
    activation="relu",
    input_shape=[None, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(60, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(60, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 100)
])
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
 optimizer=optimizer,
 metrics=["mae"])
history = model.fit(train_set,epochs=1000)
```

5. Create the predictions of the last 10 points in the dataset

```
def model_forecast(model, series, window_size):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    ds = ds.window(window_size, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.flat_map(lambda w: w.batch(window_size))
    ds = ds.batch(32).prefetch(1)
    forecast = model.predict(ds)
    return forecast
rnn_forecast = model_forecast(model, series[..., np.newaxis], window_size)
print(rnn_forecast[split_time - window_size:])
rnn_forecast = rnn_forecast[split_time - window_size:-1, -1, 0]
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(time_valid, x_valid)
plt.plot(time_valid, rnn_forecast)
```

But these are all known points, how do I change it to predict the points in the future without a validation set? (As it is already validated to be a proper model)

Comment: Do you have the `x_test` array for the test set?

Comment: It seems that your model is trained to forecast one day ahead, so if you want to generate the forecasts for several days in the future you need to implement multi-step forecasting, you can find some (own) examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787683/11989081) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70421046/11989081).

Comment: I do not have a x_test for test or anything, what is this needed for? @kkgarg

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino thanks for your reply! But what i have does not forecast anything ahead right? I had 48 datapoints in the original dataset and 48 in the end?