# How to use the LSTM model for multi-step LABEL forecast?

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, lstm

[How to use the LSTM model for multi-step forecasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785891/how-to-use-the-lstm-model-for-multi-step-forecasting)
In this post, the desired network is designed for the regression output. But I want to use LSTM classification labels for the next 5 steps. What should be the design of the network? This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *


batch_size = 32
seq_len = 128
nume_epoch = 50
num_candles = 5

train_path = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(train_path)
df_train = df[:int(len(df)*0.8)]
df_val   = df[int(len(df)*0.84):]

num_labels   = len(df_train['label'].unique())
Y_train_data = df_train['label'].values
Y_val_data   = df_val['label'].values
Y_train_data = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train_data, num_classes=num_labels)
Y_val_data   = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_val_data, num_classes=num_labels)

df_train.drop(columns=['label'], inplace=True)
df_val.drop(columns=['label'], inplace=True)
train_data = df_train.values
val_data   = df_val.values


X_train, y_train = [], []
for i in range(seq_len, len(train_data) - num_candles):
    X_train.append(train_data[i - seq_len:i])
    y_train.append(Y_train_data[i:i + num_candles])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

X_val, y_val = [], []
for i in range(seq_len, len(val_data) - num_candles):
    X_val.append(val_data[i - seq_len:i])
    y_val.append(Y_val_data[i:i + num_candles])
X_val, y_val = np.array(X_val), np.array(y_val)

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(128))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    return model

model = create_model()
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('LSTM_Class_.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', 

save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nume_epoch, callbacks=[callback], validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

but this give me this error:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 5, 2) and (None, 2) are incompatible

Comment: Can you post data.csv?

Comment: are you trying to predict the softmax of multiple labels?

Comment: @golden-lion I want to predict labels for 5 next row, labels can be binary or have multiple value.

Comment: Lstm can be used for multi label output.   Have you thought about using a restrictive boltzmann to learn the outcomes